# Bootstrap not completing 12 columns and starting new row

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

**HTML**

```
 <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <ul>Server-Side Scripting Languages<li>ASP</li><li>ASP.NET </li><li>ASP.NET MVC</li><li>Hack</li><li>JavaScript</li><li>Java</li><li>PHP</li><li>Python</li><li>Ruby</li></ul>
                     </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <ul>Client-Side Scripting Languages<li>JavaScript</li><li>ActionScript</li><li>Dart</li><li>VBScript</li><li>Typescript</li><li>Python</li></ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <ul>PHP Frameworks<li>Cake PHP</li><li>Laravel</li><li>JOOMLA</li><li>Fuel PHP</li><li>Yii</li><li>Code Igniter</li><li>Zend Framework</li></ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <ul>Javascript Frameworks<li>Angular JS</li><li>Dojo</li><li>Ext JS</li><li>Ember JS</li><li>jQuery</li><li>Kendo UI</li><li>Backbone JS</li><li>Underscore JS</li></ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <ul>Mobile App Development<li>Android</li><li>iOS</li><li>Windows</li><li>Blackberry</li><li>FireFox</li><li>SailFish</li><li>Ubuntu</li></ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <ul>Database<li>MySql</li><li>Mongo DB</li><li>RDS</li><li>Redis</li><li>Dynamo</li><li>Cassandra</li></ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <ul>CSS Frame-works<li>Bootstrap</li><li>Pure CSS</li><li>Unsemanitc</li><li>960 Grid system</li><li>Cascade Framework</li><li>Foundation</li></ul>
                    </div>
```

Update 1: JSFiddle Link
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alaksandarjesus/xz138dv9/3/)

Here is my problem. I generate this data using ajax call and want to display data on multiple formats on different resolutions.
md & lg -> 4 in a row
sm -> 2 in a row
xs -> 1 in a row.

Now only xs is fine. When i see the output, the second row for md, lg and sm are not in a good alignment.

If i set the height of the div then it works fine. but you can see the gap difference between each and every ul.

**Remove the below code from jsfiddle and you can understand the difference**

```
    div{
height:200px;
}
```

Comment: Remove the code, it says, but I can't find that code in your fiddle...

Comment: Can you check this. http://jsfiddle.net/alaksandarjesus/xz138dv9/3/

Comment: Ah, so what you want, is to make sure that Mobile App Development is in the first column, when there are four columns displayed... I think I get it

Comment: yes. I have updated the jsfiddle with border http://jsfiddle.net/alaksandarjesus/xz138dv9/9/. You can see here the php frameworks is sticking to clientside scripting language column.

Comment: I hope my answer works for you. You'll have to implement some kind of loop who inserts the clearfixes after every fourth (md) every other that is not a fourth(sm) and the rest(xs)

Comment: I was thinking about clear-fix and was struggling how to use it. Thanks for the reference. I will try to get it into my code and keep you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned something new: You need clearfix! It can appearently provide breakpoints at specific places, and you can set visibility to the different resolutions.

```
 <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <ul>Server-Side Scripting Languages<li>ASP</li><li>ASP.NET </li><li>ASP.NET MVC</li><li>Hack</li><li>JavaScript</li><li>Java</li><li>PHP</li><li>Python</li><li>Ruby</li></ul>
                     </div>
                     <div class="clearfix visible-xs"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <ul>Client-Side Scripting Languages<li>JavaScript</li><li>ActionScript</li><li>Dart</li><li>VBScript</li><li>Typescript</li><li>Python</li></ul>
                    </div>
<div class="clearfix visible-sm"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <ul>PHP Frameworks<li>Cake PHP</li><li>Laravel</li><li>JOOMLA</li><li>Fuel PHP</li><li>Yii</li><li>Code Igniter</li><li>Zend Framework</li></ul>
                    </div>
<div class="clearfix visible-xs"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <ul>Javascript Frameworks<li>Angular JS</li><li>Dojo</li><li>Ext JS</li><li>Ember JS</li><li>jQuery</li><li>Kendo UI</li><li>Backbone JS</li><li>Underscore JS</li></ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <ul>Mobile App Development<li>Android</li><li>iOS</li><li>Windows</li><li>Blackberry</li><li>FireFox</li><li>SailFish</li><li>Ubuntu</li></ul>
                    </div>
<div class="clearfix visible-xs"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <ul>Database<li>MySql</li><li>Mongo DB</li><li>RDS</li><li>Redis</li><li>Dynamo</li><li>Cassandra</li></ul>
                    </div>
<div class="clearfix visible-sm"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <ul>CSS Frame-works<li>Bootstrap</li><li>Pure CSS</li><li>Unsemanitc</li><li>960 Grid system</li><li>Cascade Framework</li><li>Foundation</li></ul>
                    </div>
```

You can read more here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets
And see the edited JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/4gk4n59t/

Comment: Thanks for your work. I got it. I paste my code as another answer.

Answer (score 0):

this is how i achieved the task as per @KjetilNordin.

```
windowWidth = $(window).width();
i = 1;
`//loop starts here
  i=i+1;

if(windowWidth > 1200  && i> 4){technologieslist=technologieslist+'<div class="clearfix"></div>';i=1;}
            if(windowWidth <= 1200 && windowWidth > 992  && i > 4){technologieslist=technologieslist+'<div class="clearfix"></div>';i=1;}
            if(windowWidth <= 992 && windowWidth >= 768 && i > 2){technologieslist=technologieslist+'<div class="clearfix"></div>';i=1;} 
 //loop ends here
```